# File disappears from Change Palette window after target stream is selected

Tags: accurev

I am facing the following strange behaviour in accurev GUI:

*Scenario:*

1. File is selected in the list of active files in a stream
2. It is sent to Change Palette
3. Another one stream selected from the list

*Result:*

File disappeared from the list.

What can cause it?

**NOTE:** File does not exist in the target stream, but target directory exists there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the mergelist command in the CLI manual.  This is the command that is being called by the GUI when you do a change palette operation.

See the section that details the mergelist algorithm, that will explain why the files are disappearing.